# Understanding a certain proof of: Euler (totient) function is (numbertheoretically) multiplicative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I try to understand a proof of the Lemma that the Euler (totient) function $\varphi$ is multiplicative for coprimes $a$,$b$:
$\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$. The proof is from Scheja/Storch: "Lehrbuch der Algebra".

Various proofs have been discussed here already, especially this [Induction in proof of multiplicativity of Euler totient function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195493/induction-in-proof-of-multiplicativity-of-euler-totient-function) seems to me based on the same arguments and very closely related, however I still fail to see it clearly. It uses $m=\sum_{d|m}\varphi(m)$ and (transfinite) induction. Here it goes:

$\varphi(1\cdot1) = \varphi(1)\cdot\varphi(1)$ holds.

Then we assume it holds for anything smaller than $ab$. Let $d$ be a divisor of $ab$ then there is a unique factorisation $rs$ of d with $r|a$ and $s|b$, so that the set of all divisors $d$ of $ab$ can be written like $\{rs:r|a,s|b\}$, so we get
$$ ab=\sum_{d|ab}\varphi(d) $$
$$ = \varphi(ab) - \varphi(a)\varphi(b) + \sum_{r|a,s|b}\varphi(r)\varphi(s)$$
$$ = \varphi(ab) - \varphi(a)\varphi(b) + \Big(\sum_{r|a}\varphi(r)\Big) \Big(\sum_{s|b}\varphi(s)\Big)$$
$$ = \varphi(ab) - \varphi(a)\varphi(b) + ab $$
That gives $\varphi(ab) - \varphi(a)\varphi(b) = 0$ which is the induction step. $\blacksquare$

I believe I understand everything except how the second equation comes up. Here I understand that $\sum_{d|ab}\varphi(d) = \sum_{r|a,s|b} \varphi(rs)$. Then by inductions assumption $\sum_{r|a,s|b} \varphi(rs) = \sum_{r|a,s|b} \varphi(r)\varphi(s) $, for all terms except $\varphi(ab)$. From here on I get lost (please help).

Comment: Sorry I just in the second after editing the question and posting I got it! Does it make sense when I give the answer? It is: $\sum_{d|ab}\varphi(d) = \sum_{r|a,s|b}\varphi(rs) = \sum_{r\neq a \land s\neq b} \varphi(r)\varphi(s) + \varphi(ab) = \sum \varphi(r)\varphi(s) + \varphi(ab) - \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term $-\phi(a)\phi(b)$ cancels out with the summand, for which $r=a$ and $s=b$.
For every smaller divisor the induction step is used. So, we have the sum of the euler-phi-functions for all divisors but $ab$ and finally $\phi(ab)$, so the second and third expression are equivalent.